# Error in dynamically setting state in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am dynamically trying to set input values in react-hooks concept, but I am encountering an error. Could someone help me with this:

Code:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

function ObjectHook() {
    var [names,setName]=useState({fname:'',lname:''});
    let UpdateData = (event) =>{
        setName({...names,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <input type='text' name='fname' value={names.fname} onChange={UpdateData}>First Name</input>
            <input type='text' name='lname' value={names.lname} onChange={UpdateData}>Last Name</input>
            <h1>{names.fname}</h1>
            <h1>{names.lname}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ObjectHook;
```

here is the  error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use placeholder instead of child text

```
<input type='text' name='fname' value={names.fname} onChange={UpdateData} placeholder='First Name' />
```

Answer (score 1):

[inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) don't accept children. Meaning you can't do this ...

```
<input>text</input>
```

You can use the input [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefplaceholder) attribute, but placeholders are not [accessible](https://www.deque.com/blog/accessible-forms-the-problem-with-placeholders/).

The best thing to do is use a label.

```
<label>
  First Name<
  <input />
</label>
<label>
  Last Name<
  <input />
</label>
```